# Translation of "The weather is great"

Tags: traduction

"The weather is great today!"

What are the possible translations of this sentence?

> (1) Le temps est très beau aujourd'hui !
>
> (2) La météo est très belle aujourd'hui !
>
> (3) Il fait très beau aujourd'hui !
>
> (4) Il fait super/magnifique/fantastique/merveilleux aujourd'hui !

What if the sentence instead refers to the weather of a place in general? For example:

"The weather in Paris in the summer is great!"

> (5) Le temps à Paris est très beau en été !
>
> (6) La météo à Paris est très belle en été !
>
> (7) Il fait très beau à Paris en été !
>
> (8) Il fait super/magnifique/fantastique/merveilleux à Paris en été !
>
> (9) Le climat à Paris est très beau en été !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1: ok
- 2: La météo est bonne / est au beau fixe aujourd'hui !
- 3: ok
- 4: Il fait super beau aujourd'hui ! (colloquial); Il fait un temps merveilleux aujourd'hui !
- 5: ok
- 6: À Paris, la météo est très bonne en été !
- 7: ok
- 8: Il fait un temps magnifique à Paris en été !
- 9: À Paris, le climat est très agréable en été !

Answer (score 0):

Il fait un temps formidable aujourd'hui.